# Content of PHP include is not working with local page css

Tags: php, html, css, include

In my html page, I use a PHP include to insert my site-wide header:

`<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`

Here is the code in header.php:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" class="active">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us.php" id="nav_about">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="competition.php" id="nav_competition">competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.php" id="nav_media">media</a></li>
                <li><a href="sponsors.php" id="nav_sponsors">sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_us.php" id="nav_contact">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the CSS in the header of the HTML document:

```
#nav_about { color:#4c005c; }
```

The "active" class in the inserted code is to change the color of that link to signify what page you are on.  That functions fine, as "active" is defined in the CSS document linked to the html file.  I want to modify the color of a particular link depending on what page it is included in.  Thing is, the CSS on that page (the one defining #nav_about) does not apply when I test it out.  The include works fine though.

In summary, I need to find a way to modify a site-wide snippet of HTML that is inserted via a PHP include with CSS on that page it is inserted in.

I am new to HTML and PHP, so I assume it is some lack of knowledge here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Are you asking how to include the CSS file?

Comment: Are you including the CSS file correctly?  In firefox, you can view source and click on the CSS path (inside the `<link ...>` tag).  You should see your CSS.  If not, you likely have a relative path issue.

Comment: The CSS is all included just fine.  From what I read, a PHP include is akin to pasting in the new code before the document is sent to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a selector specificity issue.  What's the CSS for your navigation links?

If it's something like `#navigation li {color: #abc}`, that will take priority over the `#nav_about` selector.

Selector specificity is ranked by the number of ids, classes, and elements in each.

**1 id + 1 element > 1 id**.

Increase the specificity of the `#nav_about` selector (e.g. change it to  `#navigation #nav_about`) and you should be fine.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  Yes, it is quite specific in my CSS document.  I'll try this before I do any of the other suggestions.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Basic CSS there.  Now to look into the other answers... you get the check due to solving the problem in the most direct way.

Comment: Cheers.  I had a feeling! :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do change the class of the HTML element based on the current page you are on in PHP might look something like this:

```
<?php
$nav_links = array(
    '/index.php' => array('id' => 'nav_home', 'label' => 'Home'),
    '/about_us.php' => array('id' => 'nav_about', 'label' => 'About Us'),
    // and so on for each link
);
?>
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
<?php
foreach ($nav_links as $href => $link_info) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $href) {
?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" id="<?php echo $link_info['id']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $link_info['label']; ?></a></li>
<?php
    } else {
?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" id="<?php echo $link_info['id']; ?>"><?php echo $link_info['label']; ?></a></li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here you would just apply class=`active` for the link that corresponds to the currently viewed page. This also makes it really easy to separate out you page/link configuration if you so desire.

Comment: I didn't want to get too deep into PHP yet, thus my use of CSS.  This is quite enticing!  I'll investigate this in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the traditional way, inside the PHP tags,

```
<?php
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='css-filename.css' type='text/css'>";
 ?>
```